# Buscar parametros en una url

Tags: javascript, url, parametros

necesito capturar el valor de los parametros de una url.

**Tengo lo siguiente**:
una url con 3 parametros:

```
var url_str = 'www.landing/prueba.html?banner=parametro1&imagen=paramtero2&ch=parametro3'

var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(url_str);
var imagen = urlParams.get('imagen');
var ch = urlParams.get('ch');
```

**Este codigo funciona perfecto,** porque trae el valor de cada parametro, lo que viene despues del &.

**El problema es**, cuando quiero llamar el primer parametro, que viene despues del "?"

```
var banner = urlParams.get('banner');
```

El resultado de esta variable es null, ya que no logra identificarlo.

**La pregunta es**: ¿cómo puedo identificar el primer parametro que en la url está despues del ? y no tiene el signo &?

Gracias!
uso Javascript.

Comment: Te recomiendo completar el [tour] para conocer mejor el sitio y ganar una medalla ;)

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un pequeño error al usar la clase URLSearchParams: no se le ha de pasar toda la URL, sino la parte tras el `?`

```js
const url_str = 'www.landing/prueba.html?banner=parametro1&imagen=paramtero2&ch=parametro3'

//necesitas la URL completa, incluyendo el protocolo
const url = new URL('https://' + url_str);
//substring con los search params
console.log(url.search);

//aquí tienes dos opciones
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
const urlParams2 = url.searchParams;

//son equivalentes
for (const [key, value] of urlParams) {
  console.log(key,':',value);
}

for (const [key, value] of urlParams2) {
  console.log(key,':',value);
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Pablo, funcionó perfecto!

Answer (score 0):

uso URLSearchParams de esta forma simple  para evitar errores

```js
var paramsString= 'q=www.landing/prueba.html.searchParams&banner=parametro1&imagen=paramtero2&ch=parametro3'

var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);

const u=urlParams.get("banner")
console.log(u)
console.log(urlParams.get("imagen"))
console.log(urlParams.get("ch"))
for (let p of urlParams) {
  console.log(p);
}
/*
node /tmp/Hy1UCBU5fB.js
parametro1
paramtero2
parametro3
[ 'q', 'www.landing/prueba.html.searchParams' ]
[ 'banner', 'parametro1' ]
[ 'imagen', 'paramtero2' ]
[ 'ch', 'parametro3' ]

*/
```